# How to deal with wide-character directory entries in C?

Tags: c, file, directory, widechar, dirent.h

I have looked up various methods of converting wide strings to single-byte characters, but am unsure how to approach the `char d_name[260]` field of a `struct dirent` entry pertaining to a file with a wide character name.

Is the `d_name` field completely invalid or is there any way to obtain a valid wide string or single-byte string from it?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Updates:

Platform: Windows 10

Compiler: MinGW

Problematic section of code (minimum reproducible example):

```
struct dirent *entry;
DIR *dir = opendir(srcDir);
time_t mtime = 0;
size_t PDFlen = 260 + HPlen + 12 + 1;
char *PDF = malloc(PDFlen);
char finalPDF[264] = {0};
memset_c(PDF, 0, PDFlen);
while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    if (endswith(entry->d_name, ".pdf")) {
        strcpy_c(PDF, srcDir); strcat_c(PDF, "\\"); strcat_c(PDF, entry->d_name);
        stat64(PDF, &buffer);
        if (buffer.st_mtime > mtime) {
            mtime = buffer.st_mtime;
#ifdef _WIN32
            strcpy_c(finalPDF, "\\");
#else
            strcpy_c(finalPDF, "/");
#endif
            strcat_c(finalPDF, entry->d_name);
        }
    }
}
```

... then later on I am unable to open `finalPDF` with `fopen()`, hence my question (finalPDF is a PDF file in Spanish whose filename contains two non-ASCII characters).

P.S. `srcDir` is my Downloads folder and `HPlen` is the number of characters in my home path.

Comment: What platform?  Linux?  If so, `d_name` will be UTF-8, so you can work with that.

Comment: @PaulSanders thank you for your suggestions, I have amended my question. I'm on Windows, and I know the Windows API has ample support for wchars, but I am trying to make my code as portable as possible. I would be happy to write my own conversion function, but am unsure what is actually contained within the ```d_name``` field as a result of the non-ASCII file path.

Comment: I'd write a little program and take a look in the debugger.  But Windows likely screws this up, you're better off using the native wide-character (Unicode) APIs there.

Comment: @PaulSanders cheers, I will have to probably end up doing that! I'll tinker around a little with it now

Comment: OK, gl.  My own code runs on Windows and macOS and I put things like this behind an API so that I can implement the required code separately for each (and the code that then uses it is cross-platform).

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl The code in question won't work by default on Windows, as `opendir()`/`readdir()` don't exist in Microsoft's APIs. So, unless your compiler provides its own version of them, or you find a 3rd party port, you are better off `#ifdef`'ing your code to use the Win32 equivalents instead - `Find(First|Next)FileW()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau MinGW may do (and it might even work properly).

Comment: @Gregor The problem might actually be with `fopen`.  Break out the debugger!

Comment: @PaulSanders looking at [MinGW's implementation](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/misc/dirent.c), it is based on `TCHAR`, so whether it uses `char[]` or `wchar_t[]` for the file/directory names depends on how it is compiled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh right, that's useful information OP.  Compile for UNICODE then (however MinGW handles that) and use `_tfopen` instead of `fopen`, although that has grave consequences for portability.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you to you and @PaulSanders for all this valuable information. I have always had ```<dirent.h>``` work on Windows, so had never really given it much thought (although I was aware that it was natively written for unix systems), so I will definitely look into using FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile() in Win32. Lots more ```#ifdef```'ing indeed! Cheers